# difference between past and last hour

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between "The traffic is running smoothly for **past** 2 hours" and "The traffic is running smoothly for **last** 2 hours"

Comment: They are synonyms in this context, meaning "immediately previous". You need to put "**the**" before "**past/last**".

Comment: The meanings overlap, but there is a possible difference. *The past two hours* would refer to the two hours before now. *The last two hours* could refer to the two hours before now or (depending on context) the final two hours of an ongoing event.

Comment: You could redundantly say... *for the last past two hours.*

Comment: You can also say _the two hours past_ but you can't say *_the two hours last_. The constructions have grown together but they're still different. _Past_ is still a participle to some degree, but _last_ has passed that boundary.

Comment: @user 66974 But no one does!

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to note is that the two words are not true synonyms. You could **not** say, for example, "I was away past week". But you could say "I was away *last* week".

It is when you refer to a measured period of time with the definite article, such as "*the last hour*" or "*the past hour*" as in your examples, that they are interchangeable and mean the same thing.

While there may be no explainable difference between the two, there is a need to be more specific about certain periods of time which could be ambiguous. For example, "last year" generally refers to the last complete calendar year - so if someone said in 2023, "*I went on holiday last year*", you would imagine they went away during 2022. But "*I've been busy this past year*" could mean the most recent 12 months rather than a year on the calendar. Likewise with "*this past month*", it could refer to a period of roughly 4 weeks rather than a calendar month. And "*the last hour*" could mean the last 60 minutes rather than an hour marked on the clock. In cases like this where we mean to refer to a period marked on the calendar or the clock we tend to avoid either 'the last [x]' or 'the past [x]' altogether.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

See [last](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=last):

> 3. Just past; most recent: last year; the last time I checked.

See [past](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=past)

> b. Just gone by or elapsed: in the past few days